# Minimizing and Handling Deadlocks Strategies

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

I want to discuss `deadlock` minimizing strategies. From `isolation level` to retries to different insert strategies.

Lets say we have table A:

```
CREATE TABLE `A` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `changing_data_a` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `changing_data_b` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=INNODB
```

And lets say we get data from multiple providers(100k+ new/updated rows per day), `name` is unique and `changing_data_a` and `changing_data_b` data can be updated from time to time.

Main queries to run against this table:

1. The instrets of course.
2. Selects by id
3. Selects by name
4. Updating `changing_data` columns by name

What would be your inserting strategy?

1. `IODKU` small batches from any number or threads(same as number of providers) with isolation level `Read Committed` and 3 retries in case of a deadlock.
2. Caching the data in memory of the application, inserting from a single thread every x minutes.
3. Caching the data in a help table without unique key, summarizing the data every x minutes

Any other strategy?

Also would like to add to this post the MySQL documentation regarding deadlocks handling: [How to Minimize and Handle Deadlocks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-deadlocks-handling.html)

Comment: Show us the main queries used against this table.  There are tricks that _may_ be useful for speeding up the queries, hence decreasing the chance of deadlocks.

Comment: @Rick James updated

Comment: Sounds like `PRIMARY KEY(name), INDEX(id)`  is slightly better.  Perhaps the queries are part of longer transactions, and that is part of the deadlock hassle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "normalization" table?  That is, it is a mapping from `name` to a shorter `id`?

If so, simply remove it from the transaction.  You don't really need to rollback if there is a failure.  At worst, you might have a few extra rows in the table that are never used.  Outside the main transaction, have `autocommit=ON`.  And, there is probably no need for IODKU, so simply use `INSERT IGNORE`.

Change from

```
UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
```

to

```
PRIMARY KEY(name),
INDEX(id)   -- sufficient for auto_increment
```

Rationale:  Multiple unique indexes slows down INSERTs.

Caveat:  Under what conditions do you look at the "changing_date" columns?  If you are coming from `id`, then your indexes are better due to clustering.

Another thing to note:  All(?) forms of `INSERT`, including IODKU, "burn" ids.  That is, you will find lots of gaps in the id values.

Since you are inserting at a mere 1+/second, I don't think you need any kind okf batching.  But if they do come to you in clumps, then here is a discussion of how to do that efficiently: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization

Comment: so from the post you related, you suggest using a staging table like in the example to pile up rows and then update the main table every x mins + truncating it?